# Stuck in Charles Proxy Certificate Installation for Kindle Fire TV stick

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, amazon-fire-tv, charles-proxy

We started working on Fire TV stick recently and we need to connect charles proxy tool for ease of development process.

We were able to set up proxy using the command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.amazon.ssm/.ControlPanel
```

But we are not getting any way to install the charles trusted certificate in Fire tv. We tried the approach mentioned in the following url:

> https://developer.amazon.com/fr/blogs/appstore/post/58201cb3-9b41-4567-a037-65a9d4f979a7/viewing-secure-ssl-https-traffic-from-your-app-on-fire-tvs-running-fire-os-6

Any help would be really appreciated.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you were able to solve your issue but if you didn't.

You can follow these instructions: https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/fire-tv/system-xray-developer-tools.html#network-proxy

Reply back if you are not able to get it to work.

Update:(new link) https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/network-proxy.html

Comment: Yes we had followed same link to get it done. Thanks for the reply. Appreciated..!!!

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: new link added @Chris